# How to call python from coffeescript

Tags: angularjs, python-2.7, coffeescript

I am hacking an example angularjs app created using coffeescript.  I'm new to both but have a fair amount of xp with python.

How can I call flask from within a coffeescript script?

Specifically, the eg app instantiates an array:

```
.controller('tableCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$filter'
    ($scope, $filter) ->
        # filter
        $scope.stores = [
            {name: 'Nijiya Market', price: '$$', sales: 292, rating: 4.0}
            {name: 'Eat On Monday Truck', price: '$', sales: 119, rating: 4.3}
...
       ]
       ...
```

and then a bunch of other setup on the `stores` array.  Instead of this static list in the coffeescript file, I want to call a python script from within this script (which fetches rows from a DB).

Any help would be appreciated - such as a good online resource I can read.  I can't seem to find any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use the builtin [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service to make the call to the server. For some sugar you have the option of using the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service which wraps the $http service. Ideally you'd create a method in a service of your own making to call from your controller..

my controller (with my service injected)

```
angular.module 'app'

.controller 'RegisterFormCtrl', (UsersService) ->
  UsersService.create(@details)
    .then()....
```

my service (with my resource injected)

```
angular.module('app')

.factory 'UsersService', (UsersResource) ->
  new class
    constructor: ->
      @response = null

    # register
    create: (user) ->
      UsersResource.save(user).$promise
```

my resource

```
angular.module('app')

.factory "UsersResource", (Resty) ->
  Resty "/api/users/:id", {id: '@id'}

.factory "UserKeysResource", ($resource) ->
  $resource "/api/userkeys"
```

my resource actually uses another service of mine which uses the angular $resource service..

```
angular.module('app')

.factory "Resty", ($resource) ->

  (url, params, methods, options) ->
    methods = angular.extend {
      update:
        method: 'PUT'
      create:
        method: 'POST'
    }, methods

    options = angular.extend { idAttribute: 'id' }, options

    resource = $resource url, params, methods

    resource.prototype.$save = () ->
      if this[options.idAttribute]
        this.$update.apply this, arguments
      else
        this.$create.apply this, arguments

    resource
```

ok, so the bare minimum alternative implementation, in your controller, would be the following..

```
.controller('tableCtrl', [
  '$scope', '$filter', '$http',
  ($scope, $filter, $http) ->
      # filter

    $http.get('/someUrl').
    success(
      (data, status, headers, config) ->
        # this callback will be called asynchronously
        # when the response is available
        $scope.stores = data
    ).
    error(
      (data, status, headers, config) ->
        # called asynchronously if an error occurs
        # or server returns response with an error status.
    )
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I kind of get it, but I'm at a level more noob than required to fully understand.  Can I put all these controllers in one file?  I don't need it to look good at this stage, just function to extract data from flask.